# Default From address in iOS Mail

Tags: ios, mail.app, contacts

I have multiple e-mail addresses associated with My Contact on my iPhone (6S, iOS 10.0.2). Some of those e-mail addresses are for accounts on the phone and some are for accounts not on the phone.

If I set the default mail account in iOS using `Settings->Mail->Default Account`, this does not directly control the `From` address selection of the outgoing mail. Probably this makes sense, because the `From` address can be set independently of the account used to send. Most advice I find in other questions/Web search only centres on this setting, which doesn't appear to be the only thing which is relevant.

When I compose a new e-mail, the selected `From` address is by default one which is a) not for the default account in Settings; b) not even an account which is setup on the phone. This is very undesirable.

As I enter the recipient name, the `From` address sometimes changes. It can change to at least 3 other values (all from My Contact, all from accounts on the phone). This could possibly be learning behaviour based on previously sent e-mails. These choices are often not ideal but better than the default choice.

How is the `From` address selection controlled? Can I at least control the default, even if the "intelligent" behaviour cannot be controlled? The default is almost always a poor choice for me, and I have to remember to manually check the choice and switch it every time.

Comment: See https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/icloud/mmbffbba6600/icloud

Comment: That doesn't seem relevant - it's about the iCloud web UI.

Comment: Yeah, it could still help. I should have added that as "related". ;)